# Can't format microSD card

Tags: formatting

I am trying to format a microSD card which was previously used in a Windows Phone. Currently the microSD card is in a Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus (GT-S7500) running Android 2.3.6. I have tried erasing the memory from the Settings menu and now I have plugged the USB and givin it a go from Ubuntu.

Every time I try to format (or manually delete) data, every file and directory seem to stay put.

I thought it could be a microSD card corruption problem, but as I type

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sdc
```

The only warning message I get is:

```
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
Automatically removing dirty bit.
```

Then I issue the command one more time and the check is fine.

Is there anything I can do to format this microSD card?

Update: Running `gparted` I get this error:

```
plain floppy: device "/dev/sdc" busy (Resource temporarily unavailable):
Cannot initialize '::'
mlabel: Cannot initialize drive
```

Comment: From the context (also the one given on the answer), it might be worth trying: `sudo cfdisk /dev/sdc`, delete the partition, re-create it, and then create the file system anew (which should be possible via the Android device by formatting it). This time it's a "clean partition" then, so nothing should be "locked".

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in fsck.

```
 # fsck.vfat -v -a -w /dev/sda1
```

The above command automatically write changes to disk.

*The dirty bit is set and cleared in the kernel, when mounting and unmounting a device;*

or if its not working try this [HDD Low Level Format Tool](http://ccm.net/download/download-815-hdd-low-level-format-tool).This will help you format microSD completely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately all files are still on the microSD card.

Comment: Can u please recheck the SD Card whether it is locked or not? And i have updated the Answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It seems to be locked. I tried to write a new file on the microSD and on the next mount it was gone.  Unfortunately I can't use Windows.